# NuGet package dependencies and build/deploy servers

Tags: deployment, nuget, build-process, artifacts

We're using FluentMigrator (a NuGet package) on an ASP.net/MVC project to maintain database changes to our SQL Server.

**What is the "correct" way to distribute a NuGet package with other build artifacts for usage during a deployment? Do I only need the "packages" folder?**

I'm hoping for a response other than "use package manager and install the Nuget package on PROD".

I don't want to pull the package (from either local or non-local sources) during deployment, I want to include the correct package with my compiled code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to pull the package down before *building* the project, then assuming your project references the assembly such that Copy Local is true, it will be included in the build output, which should be stored as an artifact in your CI tool.

You definitely should not be doing anything related to NuGet beyond this point in your build/deployment process.

Comment: We're using Fluent Migrator and in addition to the dll's referenced for the build (which are CopyLocal=True) we use an exe (and the files it's dependent on) from the package to push our DB changes. To put it more clearly, we have a build-time dependency on the package but we also have a deploy-time dependency on the package. I don't want to pull the package down during deployment, I want to distribute it with my app.

Comment: Can you set the Build Action of the .exe file to content in the VS properties window? That way it will be treated as a stand-alone file and be included in the output. You could also embed it as a resource, write it out to disk at runtime - depends on what exactly you need.